# Create a button with a double border?

Tags: css

The button I want:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2Qv4.png (I don't have enough reputation to post images)]

I have tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
button {
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    border: 3px double #f26700;
    background: #f26700;
}
```

How can i display this white line with CSS?

Comment: you can add a box-shadow:0 0 0 1px orange or an outline:solid orange 1px;

Comment: You can use two `div`s it's a tricky solution. With some margin in the first , *or padding in the second* and border orange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as commented, 2 easy  options :
box-shadow and outline:

```
button {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: #f26700;
  outline:solid #f26700 1px;
  padding:0.25em 1em;
}
button + button {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #f26700;
  outline:none;
}
```

demo : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/InDqa

```css
button {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: #f26700;
  outline: solid #f26700 1px;
  padding: 0.25em 1em;
}

button+button {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #f26700;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<button>outlined</button> <button>shadowed</button>
```

Comment: The box-shadow approach works great when you have a `border-radius` and you want the outline round in Safari.

Answer (score 9):

Write:

```
button{
    border: 3px double white;
}
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/hDXU8/)

OR:

```
button{
    border: 1px double white;
    outline: 1px solid #f26700;
}
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/hDXU8/2/)

OR:

```
button{
    border: 2px solid white;
    box-shadow:0 0 0 0px white, 0 0 0 2px #F26700;
}
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/hDXU8/3/)

Comment: They don't look identical.

Comment: Then tweak it, the key is the border: 3px double #f26700;

Comment: The answer is perfect!

Comment: @yannis, to make it identical, write that roman text and add some paddings..you're good to go then..

Comment: @Hiral, there is a problem: the white border around the button :(

Comment: I can't make it work, but @Kai Feller work the same for the others.

Comment: @alan_derua I have updated answer. Hope it helps you

Comment: I think the solution with the shadow is amazing, thanks.

Comment: @AndréMachado thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the outline property:

CSS

```
.button {
    font-family:'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    line-height: 1.8em;
    border: 1px solid white;
    background: #f26700;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    outline: 1px solid #f26700;
}
```

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2kgGF/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this just with an outline.

```
button {
    width: 8rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 2.4rem;
    color: white;
    background: darkorange;
    border: none;
    outline: .1rem solid white;
    outline-offset: -.3rem;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/lrsbck/7Zp6X/